# Find the magic value from an array of N numbers

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arrays

I was asked this problem recently in an interview however, I failed to provide an optimal solution to it.

> Given an array $A$ of $n$ numbers, the magic factor of $i^{th}$ element is
> equal to the greatest prime factor $G$ where $G$ is the count of
> elements in the array strictly less than the element $A[i]$.
> Now, the magical value of the array is the **maximum possible magic
> factor** for all the elements of the array.
>
> Note: Magic factor for $G = 0$ is $0$ and for $G = 1$ is $1$.

```
Input: 1 2 3 4 5
Output: 3
```

**Explanation:** the array $A$ is $[1,2,3,4,5]$.
Magic Factors are: $[0,1,2,3,2]$.
Thus, the magical value of the array is $max(0,1,2,3,2) = 3$.

Constraints: $1 <= n <= 10^5;  
         1 <= A[i] <= 10^6$

This is my logic below.

```
public static int magicValue(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    if(arr.length == 1)
      return 1;
    int G = 2, maxMagicValue = G;
    for(int i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int magicFactor = getMagicFactor(i);
        maxMagicValue = Math.max(magicFactor, maxMagicValue);
    }
    return maxMagicValue;
}

public static int getMagicFactor(int elem) {
    int magicFactor = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= elem; i++) {
        boolean isPrime = isPrime(i);
        if(isPrime && elem % i == 0)
                magicFactor = i;
    }
    return magicFactor;
}

public static boolean isPrime(int val) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for(int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(val); j++) {
        if(val % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```

However it failed for the below test case and gave a $TLE$ for the rest of the test cases.

**Failed Testcase:** $A = [56, 22, 19, 40, 38, 21, 10, 1, 8, 98, 4, 565, 924, 1832, 9550]$

```
 Expected Output: 14
 My Output: 13
```

Can someone please guide if I have misunderstood the question and if there is a more efficient way of solving this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Use a prime sieve.

Comment: @orlpnHow does the prime sieve reduce the complexity for this problem? Currently I think my solution is taking $O(nlogn)$ time. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: TLEs don't care about the 'complexity' of the problem, just the runtime. And a sieve will just have a much better constant factor. That said e.g. the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) runs in $O(n \log \log n)$ time.

Comment: @orlp Thanks. I'll try using a prime sieve.

Comment: Also, @salazarin I think your solution is actually $O(n\sqrt{n})$, since for every number you run `isPrime` with complexity $O(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: @nirshahar The worst case complexity of `isPrime` is $O(\sqrt{n})$ but its average complexity is probably better.

Comment: @orlp welp, still doesn't change the fact that the prime sieve you proposed is better :)